# Cellular Automata Using Small Boards

Tags: automata, cellular-automata

I'm working on making patterns for a digital lava lamp (essentially, making interesting patterns using a 4x10 grid), and I've been looking into cellular automata. I tried implementing some variations on [Langton's Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) but it tends to loop in very boring ways. Does anyone have any suggestions for interesting automata on small boards?

The lamp I'm working on can be played with [here](http://tryion.lava.io/).

Any suggestions on a more appropriate place to post this question are welcome.

EDIT: By interesting, I mean patterns that work well on small boards. For example, 
Langton's Ant was not interesting because it always tended to find some static state over such a small board.

Comment: Are you familiar with reaction-diffusion systems?  Something like the B-Z reaction ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction ) might be a good automaton-like approach for pattern-making...

Comment: What is "interesting" for you?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki That looks both like it would be awesome and very difficult to model...I'll give it a try on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

"interesting" is very subjective.

You could try Brian's Brain or Brian's Seeds, both of which I find interesting.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seeds_%28cellular_automaton%29

While they are designed for an infinite plane, you could wrap your 4x10 grid at the top and bottom presenting a theoretical sphere instead of a plane.

As a interesting thought, you could start with Langton's ant and then add a swarm to the ant, then chose a random element of the swarm to take over control for the next X iterations.

Comment: I looked into Brian's Brain and some other variations, but they seemed to require a decently large space to really do what they do. Since looping the grid changes the expansion, it seems like it will need a different type of automaton. I may still try Brian's Brain (Implementing different rules is the easy part anyway)

Answer (score 1):

The smallest "interesting" cellular automaton I know of is an ant that counts in binary. It's the same as Langton's Ant, except where Langton's Ant turns to the right on a black (or lit) square, this one doesn't turn and just continues forward. (On a white/unlit square, it still turns to the left like Langton's does.)

(Its rule is **RN** in the "multi-color ant" naming scheme, or **120010** in the "multi-state ant" or general "turmite" naming scheme.)

It counts in single pixels, but is symmetrical around both axes, so it will use 2x10 pixels to count in 5 bits (from 0 to 31).